# embedded .wmv video object not working in firefox, works in IE

Tags: firefox, video, video-embedding

This is my code

```
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
    <tr>
        <td><object classid="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701" type="application/x-oleobject">
            <param name="src" value="../Documents/10695.wmv">

            </param><param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">

            </param><param name="stretchToFit" value="true">

            </param><param name="AutoStart" value="true">

            </param><embed pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" type="application/x-mplayer2" autostart="1" stetchToFit="1" NAME="MediaPlayer" ShowControls="1" src="../Documents/10695.wmv" />
        </object></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Video works fine in IE but will not even play in firefox. control appears to buffer but then does not play.

-thanks for the heads up

Comment: hahah, that's not what the "embedded" tag means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Firefox doesn't natively support WMV, whereas IE does. You'll need something like the [JW Player for Silverlight](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-wmv-player/) to support this.