# How to display video on html page in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video, object-tag

I did looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185357/embedded-wmv-video-object-not-working-in-firefox-works-in-ie) question, but the asker didn't got any reply. Still, I'm giving it a try.

I want to embed a video file on a html page. The code works fine on IE but doesn't work on firefox.

The code:

```
<object id="WMPlay" width="640" height="480" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,70"  standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject">
        <param name="URL" value="XYZ.wma" />        
        <param name="AutoStart" value="false" />        
        <embed name="WMplay" width="640" height="480" type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/Downloads/Contents/Products/MediaPlayer/"
            src="XYZ.wma" allowchangedisplaysize="True" showcontrols="1"
            autostart="false" showdisplay="1" showstatusbar="1">
        </embed>
    </object>
```

Please note that I'm not allowed to display video using any third party tool (like flash).

Can someone please tell what am I missing? Or a better solution..something which is browser independent... :)

Comment: Maybe you could - browser dependent - use HTML5 and the video tag:
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like firefox needs a plugin, check this test page:

http://plugindoc.mozdev.org/testpages/wmp11.html

Answer (score 1):

That's probably an issue with .wmv extension, which is a Microsoft proprietary format.
You should convert your video to a more "web-friendly" format, and use this code to ensure cross-browser/html version compatibility:
http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody

Answer (score 1):

Fire fox only displays .ogg and WebM...

www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp